# SharePoint WebsInfo Description is always Null

Tags: sharepoint-2013, server-side

I'm trying to get the Description of a Site but it's always null in WebsInfo! Can someone please help me understand this? I also tried using OpenWeb but that was messing up the URL that I passed in.

```
                var site = new SPSite(currentWeb.Url);

                string url = currentWeb.Url + @"/" + siteName;
                var webObject = site.AllWebs; 
                foreach (var web in webObject.WebsInfo)
                {
                    siteDescription = web.Description;
                }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a bug in the WebsInfo that has never been resolved!! I ended up using SPWebCollection.

```
               //This will find the current URL and iterate through it's site Collection
                var oSiteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);

                //Gets all webs meaning sub webs and their webs.
                var collWebsites = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;

                foreach (SPWeb web in collWebsites)
                {
                    if (web.ServerRelativeUrl.StartsWith(kpi.BusinessUnitUrl))
                    {
                        kpi.BusinessUnitDescription = web.Description;
                        kpi.SiteSpecificAreaDescription = web.Description;
                        var collLists = web.Lists;
                        IterateLists(collLists, false, ref kpi);
                    }
                }
```